# Display certain contents of a website into webview

Tags: android, html, image, button, webview

I'm new to Android programming.

I would like to know if I can load a certain part of a website into webview? The website is made from CSS. It contains headers and buttons that I do not want to be displayed into the webview. I would only like to display the contents in the website, like images and texts. Is this possible? If so, how?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `public void loadDataWithBaseURL (String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)` method to load a customised html, maybe your app can get the html from the site, modify it, and `loadDataWithBaseUrl` then.

Comment: But how do I go about doing that?? Also, I was planning to load webview in tabs. But I couldn't get the webview to load in the tab.